# Unique Solution of Initial Value Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, initial-value-problems

State where in the $xy$-plane the initial-value problem
$$y' = \frac {x − y}{2x + 5y}$$
is guaranteed to have a unique solution.

My intuition for this problem was that if the derivative ($y'$) is $0$, the equation will have a unique solution. But I can't find any theorem supporting my intuition.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem#:~:text=In%20mathematics%20%E2%80%93%20specifically%2C%20in%20differential,problem%20has%20a%20unique%20solution.

Comment: @Dhanvi The theorem doesn't tell how to find the interval... may you please guide me on that?

Comment: What do you mean with "unique solution"? The conditions of the existence-and-uniqueness theorem are satisfied everywhere where the denominator is not zero, that is, the domain is split by the line $y=-\frac25 x$.

Answer (score 0):

The given ODE is:
$$y' = \frac {x − y}{2x + 5y}~~~~(1)$$
Let $y=Vx \implies y'=V+xV'$
the ODE becomes
$$V+xV'=\frac{1-V}{2+5V} \implies xV'=\frac{1-3V-5V^2}{2+5V} \implies \frac{2+5V}{1-3v-5V^2} dV=\frac{dx}{x}~~~~(2)$$ $$= -\frac{1}{2} \left(\int \frac{dV}{5V^2+3V-1}+\frac{3+10V}{5V^2+3V-1} dV \right)=\ln Cx~~~~(3)$$
You may proceed from here to get a general solution as a family of curves with one constant $C$

**The uinique solution without a constant:**

Treat $V$ as constant (free of $x$), then $y'=V$, then from (1) we get
$$V=\frac{1-V}{2+5V}\implies V=\frac{-3\pm \sqrt{29}}{10}$$
So the unique(singular, essential) solutions of (1) are two fixed lines passing through origin, these are $$y=\frac{-3\pm \sqrt{29}}{10} ~x$$

Comment: I solved this equation, but I don't understand how to use the solution to find the initial condition for a unique solution. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Please see the answer now I have added the unique solutions with out a constant.